# Force to use same certificate to sign different "buildTypes" that are configured for a particular "productFlavor"?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk

**Background:**

I am generating builds using build variant. Below are the configurations:

```
signingConfigs {
    production {
        storeFile file("some_path/buildsystem/keystore/some.release.keystore.jks")
        storePassword "somepassword"
        keyAlias "somekeyalias"
        keyPassword "some"
        v2SigningEnabled false
    }

    develop {
        storeFile file(".some_path./buildsystem/keystore/someother.debug.keystore.jks")
        storePassword "someother"
        keyAlias "someotherkeyalias"
        keyPassword "someother"
        v2SigningEnabled false
    }
}

productFlavors {
    production {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.production
      }

    develop {
        applicationIdSuffix ".develop"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.develop
     }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

**Problem**

As, of now for example if I talk about flavour `production` then **`productionRelease`** uses `signingConfigs.production` to sign the apk. But, **`productionDebug`** doesn't uses `signingConfigs.production`.

**Expected output**

When I generate the signed apk I want the gradle to do the following for me:

1. **`developRelease`** and **`developDebug`** should be signed with only `signingConfigs.develop`
2. **`productionRelease`** and **`productionDebug`** should be signed with only `signingConfigs.production`

Another question that is similar to this which led me to do the above: [SHA-1 different for buildTypes (debug and release) for same productFlavors Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44584273/2870088)

Comment: I think using your production signature for debug builds might cause error such as releasing debug version to Google Play by accident. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: @auval You are very correct. I want to separate the signature in order to debug the production build if any issue arises. Secondly, there is a limit on map api request. I want to preserve the limit for actual users on production. In develop mode testers or developers can keep on testing with develop signature. FYI https://stackoverflow.com/q/44584273/2870088

Comment: You can set a different package name to debug builds in Gradle, and with a debug key you will not use up your production quota for maps

Comment: @auval I believe that by just setting the different package name won't work. applicationId should should match with certificate signature in firebase console. Even for debug builds if I go with default buildTypes.debug is not true. I need to do something as per Mani answer below. If you think there is other better or alternative way please do post your answer.

Comment: In Firebase console you will need to setup a new app for it.

Comment: My answer does not directly answer your question, rather than avoiding the need..

Comment: @auval Yes I understand that this doesn't directly answer. Thank-you. I will try to go over your suggestions.  I do agree but now there is a limit of free three apps only :-).

Answer (score 5):

Remove the 
`signingConfig signingCongigs.develop` elsewhere in the code block

And add new property within the buildTypes like

- withProduction
- withDevelop

Now add `signingConfig` to it

Thereby your updated gradle file look like as below

```
signingConfigs {
    production {
        storeFile file("some_path/buildsystem/keystore/some.release.keystore.jks")
        storePassword "somepassword"
        keyAlias "somekeyalias"
        keyPassword "some"
        v2SigningEnabled false
    }

    develop {
        storeFile file(".some_path./buildsystem/keystore/someother.debug.keystore.jks")
        storePassword "someother"
        keyAlias "someotherkeyalias"
        keyPassword "someother"
        v2SigningEnabled false
    }
}
productFlavors {
    production {
    }

    develop {
        applicationIdSuffix ".develop"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    /* NOTE: the debug block is not required because it is a default
 * buildType configuration; all of its settings are defined implicitly
 * by Gradle behind the scenes.
 */
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.production
    }

    withProduction {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.production
    }

    withDevelop {
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.develop
debuggable true

    }
}
```

In the terminal use the below gradle commmand:
`gradle assembleProduction` to generate build with production certificates
similarly `gradle assembleDevelop` or you can also use `gradle assemble`

You cannot force gradle to choose the certificates for `debug` property rather you could create own `buildTypes`

As per [documentation](https://gradle.org/maven-vs-gradle/)

> Automate signing your applications. Debug build variants are, by default, signed with a debug key for installation on development devices. Declare additional signing configurations for publication to the Google Play store.

**Update:**
As the other answer pointed out,

> Add debuggable true property under custom buildTypes against which you
>   want to debug build and see the logs.

Comment: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > ProductFlavor names cannot collide with BuildType names. This won't work

Comment: Can you post your updated gradle file with changes you made to mine?

Comment: Updated the answer rectifying the error project build and additional property of debuggable true to enable debugging

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to @Mani for throwing the light on `buildTypes.debug`.**

As per [documentation Application Signing](https://gradle.org/maven-vs-gradle/)

> Automate signing your applications. Debug build variants are, by default, signed with a debug key for installation on development devices. Declare additional signing configurations for publication to the Google Play store.

The above is very correct. **No need to remove `signingConfig` from `productFlavors`. Also, add `debuggable true` property under custom `buildTypes` against which you want to debug build and see the logs.**

**You can add below properties in `buildTypes` as per your need:**

```
{name=withDevelopDebug, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, 
jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, 
renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, 
minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, 
embedMicroApp=true, buildConfigFields={}, resValues={}, 
proguardFiles= [], consumerProguardFiles=[], manifestPlaceholders={}}
```

As, I have added `debuggable true` under `withProductionDebug` and `withDevelopDebug`

```
signingConfigs {
    production {
    storeFile file("some_path/buildsystem/keystore/some.release.keystore.jks")
    storePassword "somepassword"
    keyAlias "somekeyalias"
    keyPassword "some"        
    }

    develop {
    storeFile file(".some_path./buildsystem/keystore/someother.debug.keystore.jks")
    storePassword "someother"
    keyAlias "someotherkeyalias"
    keyPassword "someother"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    withProductionRelease{
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }

    withProductionDebug{
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
    }

    withDevelopRelease{
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }

    withDevelopDebug{
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
    }
}

productFlavors {
    production {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.production
    }

    develop {
        applicationIdSuffix ".develop"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.develop
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer your question? Question is to have same "signingConfig" based for buildTypes and not on productflavours!!

Comment: @Mani Same signingConfig is used for different buildTypes by keeping the same certificate under  productFlavors. Also, there are two gaps with your solution as I have mentioned in my answer. First regarding the A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > ProductFlavor names cannot collide with BuildType names.  Secondly,  set debuggable true for debugging the build. It doesn't matter if you put signingConfig under productFlavors or buildTypes.

Comment: "Same signingConfig is used for different buildTypes by keeping the same certificate under productFlavors." - This would lead unnecessary confusion though this trick will work!!