# Google SignIn API Exception 10

Tags: java, android, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

Approaching to the final stage of the authentification, but something is going wrong in `handleSignInResult` method. It returns Exception code 10 (Developer error) in logs. Google provides comprehensive description:

> The application is misconfigured. This error is not recoverable and will be treated as fatal. The developer is an idiot...

What should I do to handle this (get an account) and finally retrive values from account?
Thank you in advance for your help!!!

MainActivity:

```
package ru.podgorny.carcall;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        SignInButton signInButton;
        public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 07;
        public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
        TextView tw1;
        TextView tw2;


        GoogleSignInOptions gso;
        GoogleSignInClient mGSC;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity Works");
        findViews();

            gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    //.requestProfile()
                    .build();

            mGSC = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso); //smth with mGSC variable....

             View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onClick2(v);
                }
            };
             signInButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);




    }

    private void findViews() {
            Log.d (TAG, "findViews started");
        signInButton = findViewById(R.id.idButtonGoogle);

        tw1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tw1 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        Log.d(TAG, "Views finded");


    }

    public void onClick2(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick started");
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.idButtonGoogle:
                signIn();
                break;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "OnClick Started");
    }

    public void signIn() {

        Intent signInIntent = mGSC.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        Log.d(TAG, "startActivityForResult works");

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "OnActivityResult started");
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
            // a listener.
            Log.d(TAG, "TASK started");
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
            Log.d(TAG, "OnActivityResult returned");
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);//ERROR -- Code 10
            Log.d(TAG, "Account received");


            updateUI(account);
            Log.d(TAG, "updateUI Launched");
        } catch (ApiException e) {

            Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
            updateUI(null);
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
            if (account!=null) {
                tw1.setText("OK");
                tw2.setText("Name: " + account.getGivenName() + ", Family name: " + account.getFamilyName() + ", Email: " + account.getEmail() /*+ " image: " +
                        account.getPhotoUrl()*/);
            }else {
                tw1.setText("SMTH wrong");
            }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This error might happen if you are not using same project at **console.developers.google** and **console.firebase.google.com**. If project is same at both console make sure you have add your **SHA1** Key properly. Get **SHA1** from Android studio.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open your Project
3. Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)
4. Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar, you will see List Gradle scripts of your Project)
5. Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List (root))
6. Click on Tasks
7. Click on Android
8. Double Click on signingReport (You will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar(Sometimes it will be in Gradle Console))
9. Select app module from module selection dropdown to run or debug your application   You also need to get google-services.json from firebase console and put into your project.

Comment: I don't understand step 9. What do I do with the signingReport output ?

Comment: If you use Play App Signing, make sure to use SHA1 from its certificate, not your debug or release keystore

Comment: Google should add a note where they accept "SHA-1 certificate fingerprint". The current tip to use `keytool` is not valid anymore. For those still looking, go to Play Console > Setup > App Integrity > App Signing. There you will find the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint.

Comment: @PrasadDeZoysa I still get error code 10 after I added another Android OAuth client to the cloud console with the correct app package name and the SHA1-fingerprint from Google play console.
The sign in is working when running a debug build and even a release build (signed with our keystore) on a device/emulator. But when uploading an aab to Google Play internal test, I get this error 10.
Do you have any idea what else could be wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: never mind, I just found out that there is a separate SHA-fingerprint section for internal testing Google Play Console, so I had to add another OAuth client ID in cloud console, now it is working

Answer (score 27):

I landed into the same problem and wasted hours. On digging deeper into OAuth and OpenId, I figured out the reason. We are doing a conceptual error here.

**For android or any other platform (except web), you need to create at least two types of client id in the same project of google API console. These Client ID types are:**

1. Web Application
2. Android

You can create them in any order. While creating Android type Client Id, you need to give package name and SHA1. While creating Web Application Id, you just need to give a name.

You don't need to do anything with any of these id's further until you want to verify the user at your backend. In other words, if you want your backend server to ask google server about this user's information, then only you would need Web Application Id. The conceptual flow is as follows:

1. First send Web Application Client Id from Android App to Google Sign-in Server as an additional option using requestIdToken(your_web_app_client_id).
2. You will get back a token in Android app upon user's sign in.
3. Send this token to your backend.
4. Now your backend can exchange this token with Google Servers to get user's information

Send this Web Appplication Client Id from Android App to backend server.

Use this Web Application Id if you want to verify user at your backend.

Comment: thx man i solved this problem, i send cliendID but android and must be clientID web application

Comment: That's what solved it for me! I thought only the web key was being used as that's what you send in the request. And couldn't figure out why it was working on my environment and not on my colleague's!

Comment: I was using wrong id instead of 
`your_web_app_client_id`

Answer (score 7):

The answer for me was that you actually need to combine the two main answers given here:

1. Make sure that you created Google OAuth client ids for Android (one for Debug and one for release) and then assure that they have assigned the right SHA1 as described in the accepted answer.
2. Then you also need to create an **OAuth client ID for Web** and use that one for the actual SignIn:

   ```
   GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
       .requestIdToken(WEB_CLIENT_ID)
       .requestEmail()
       .build();
   ```

Comment: Have you tried this in production? It works with debug, but when publishing to app store using release apk, it gives the error again

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE As far as I know, this should work. You can check the code here: https://github.com/johannesjo/super-productivity-android/blob/master/app/src/play/java/com/superproductivity/superproductivity/Google.java 
and download the app here: 
https://github.com/johannesjo/super-productivity/releases

Comment: Thanks hugo, using the web application one is working for me in production. Google makes it so confusing I may have looked through 20+ questions on this GoogleSignIn issue...

Comment: It gives error when you upload bundle to app store. Where to add sh1 generated by play store?

Answer (score 7):

This Problem can be solved by using **WebApplication ID** and **android Client ID**

When ever you configure the project to generate id for android app , it generates 2 types of ids 1 Android 2 WebApplication ,

We need to **use 2nd one (web oAuth id)** and not the 1st one , it will be resolving your issue

Comment: It works. very weird thing from google though.

Comment: this shoudl come on top

Comment: Yes, It's working. It's confusing which client ID should be used. Most of them make mess it up with Android client and web client

Answer (score 5):

Another source of this error is adding **applicationIdSuffix** to your **Build Variants (Flavors)** in the gradle file. If you had everything working and suddenly when adding flavors the Google Sign In broke, check this configuration variable.

The **applicationIdSuffix** parameter might require a unique certificate for each suffix. I simply removed it because I didn't need to deploy different products or releases yet. Also, you can set the same configuration for each flavor programmatically.

Configure certificates build types: [Force to use same certificate to sign different "buildTypes" that are configured for a particular "productFlavor"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166152/force-to-use-same-certificate-to-sign-different-buildtypes-that-are-configured)

Answer (score 5):

I've found another source of the problem.

In my case the keys were alright, but **applicationId** field in **build.gradle** script differed from app's package name.

Small research showed that **applicationId** field value takes some kind of "precedence" before app's package name conserning Google autentication.

After commenting **applicationId** line in **build.gradle**, app autenticates itself in Google by package name.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this problem by this way

```
 GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.AUTH_ID))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

where my AUTH_ID is [image]

Answer (score 4):

This solution assumes that the root cause of your problem is that you are debugging and in that case the fingerprints of the app are different than the final production builds. To over come that:

Add your `debug.keystore`'s SHA1 and SHA256 fingerprint to your Firebase project with these steps:

1. Obtain the debug.keystore's fingerprints: Linux/Mac - `keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore`, Windows - `keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore`
2. Add these fingerprint's to your Firebases project's Android app section: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9137403?hl=en

Answer (score 4):

Option: then keep in mind that google also signs the app with the another certificate. So, you need to add the 2nd fingerprints as well.
Otherwise, you will receive this error.

Comment: This was my exact problem. I was going crazy thinking what the hell was wrong.

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi Hi, Where should i check for another certificate.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I paste the release keystore sha1 to google console, but forget add debug config !!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use **Web Client ID** from https://console.cloud.google.com and **not Android client**.
Even if it is mentioned Web application in Type column:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vshV1.png)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add Supplemental Information as to Why @Patrick R answer (above works/marked as correct). To execute your project/practice, Google Console needs to ID your app via SHA-1 key when its distributed on Google Play Market, **However**, when your are simply experimenting with Login confirmation and Proof Of Concept, then it associates the debug SHA-1 key (your app automatically generates this) for this exact purpose, keeping your testing and production changes modular.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))`.

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)) //add this line
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

Comment: i have added all this but still i get this error i have added in firebase also

Comment: Did you update your google-services.json after adding SHA 1 to firebase?

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue. *Code 10 in signed apk*. I put all the four keys from Google Play Console (Setup -> App integrity -> Play App Signing) to Firebase project and pasted new `Google-services.json` in app folder in Android Studio and then after generating Signed Apk, Google sign in worked.

Comment: Thanks @Syed Umair. This solution works for me

Answer (score 0):

atleast on the debug version, i didnt send any token and it worked...
ie,no 'requestIdToken' in GoogleSigninOptions.build()

It may not work in Release...will try ..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and non of the answers above worked for me:

If you get error code 10 that means for sure that you have a SHA problem. My solution was to go to the Firebase project, Settings Overview (top left cornet) -> Click on the Settings icon -> Project Settings. There, General tab will be first selected and you have to scroll down to SDK setup and configuration, select the Android app and make sure you enter the same SHA1/256 key that you've entered on the Google Cloud Platform when you've configured your OAuth consent screen and the credentials.

Hope this helps you too. Cheers!

Comment: of-course you have to complete setup project in google console

Answer (score 0):

Press "Sync Project with Gradle files."

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `package` parameter was missing from my `AndroidManifest.xml`, causing the SHA-1 to be generated incorrectly.  Once adding the correct package, regenerating the SHA-1, and adding it to Firebase, things are working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I set google sign-in up from a Google Cloud project. I set up the OAuth Consent Screen then manually added a Oauth 2.0 Client ID. Went through all the steps SHA1 and package and one client ID generated and I was trying to use this in the project.

What fixed it was instead setting up a new Firebase project with the SHA 1 from keystore and package name declared in manifest. Then in Firebase console: Authentication -> Sign-in method -> Add Google. Download updated google-services.json. Finally go to associated Google Cloud project (auto generates from new firebase project) APIs & Services -> Credentials. If Google auth is set up in Firebase you will see two OAuth 2.0 Client IDs. One is Android Client, the other is Web client. Copy the Web application Client ID and use this as the `serverClientId` when creating the `GoogleSignInOptions`.