# Android Google-signin get Api Exception 10: in Playstore APK

Tags: android, google-signin

It works well in debug or release mode without API exception. However, API Exception 10 occurs when APK is uploaded to Playstore.

I don’t' know the reason.

I checked SHA1 Configuration in Google Api console. But it is not wrong.
Only not work in Playstore APK.

I don't use Firebase.

[image: API Exception 10 Screenshot]

Comment: Hi, please do not include a picture of the exception message, if it is not absolutely necessary. Please edit your question and include it as text, that way it can be indexed and searched.

Comment: Please have look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450140/google-signin-api-exception-10)