# SignInResult:failed code 10. Doesn't work SignIn Google account made by example. Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-signin

I have been sitting with this problem for **5** days already. I thought the application was crashing because of the token and fingerprint  SHA-1 . Found an example where neither key nor fingerprint is used, but error 10 has not disappeared anywhere. Please help me, I am destroyed. Sorry for bad English.
How to create SignIn Google: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

**GRADLE.APP**

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'kotlin-android'
    }
    
    android {
        compileSdk 31
    
        defaultConfig {
    //        applicationId "com.example.googleapisignin"
            minSdk 26
            targetSdk 31
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
    
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'
    }
```

**GRADLE**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googleapisignin">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GoogleAPISignIn">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult

import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task

lateinit var mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
var RC_SIGN_IN = 0
lateinit var Text: TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Text = findViewById(R.id.text)
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            val task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            handleSignInResult(task)
        }
    }
    private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
        try {
            //At this point, the application crashes with an error 10.
            val account: GoogleSignInAccount = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            Text.text = account.id
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            Text.text = e.statusCode.toString()
            Log.d("SignFail", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode)
        }
    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

For earlier, just thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Google is moving to one-tap login, you should follow all the instructions step by step from here: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-started

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to make sure you've created [two projects](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/policies#separate-projects) one for test, one for production and added both Web and Android Client IDs in each project. From there double check that your manifest and calls are using the expected Client ID -- should be debug here if you're testing. Check that your Android Studio environment and settings are using the debug SHA-1 with the debug Client IDs.

Related and additional details,
[Google SignIn API Exception 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450140/google-signin-api-exception-10)

Comment: I am gettig the exception 10. How to resolve this? It not doing anything