# Ionic 6. App crashes when i make build and not opening

Tags: android, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm getting Logcat errors when I open app and the app crash when I open the app it crashing again and again. I think this is firebase issue or something need help to get rid of this problem. it's been a week I'm downgrading and upgrading all plugins but in vain and not getting any solutions.

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "fcmNotifications",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.2",
    "@capacitor-community/fcm": "^2.0.2",
    "@capacitor-firebase/authentication": "^0.3.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.5.1",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.1.1",
    "@capacitor/browser": "1.0.7",
    "@capacitor/camera": "^1.3.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.5.1",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.4",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.2.2",
    "@capacitor/push-notifications": "^1.0.9",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.8",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "firebase": "^9.8.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.2.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.2.2",
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.5.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

**And here are error from Logcat**

````
    Process: com.learn2earn.fcm, PID: 1811
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignIn;
        at dev.robingenz.capacitorjs.plugins.firebase.authentication.handlers.GoogleAuthProviderHandler.buildGoogleSignInClient(GoogleAuthProviderHandler.java:100)
        at dev.robingenz.capacitorjs.plugins.firebase.authentication.handlers.GoogleAuthProviderHandler.buildGoogleSignInClient(GoogleAuthProviderHandler.java:78)
        at dev.robingenz.capacitorjs.plugins.firebase.authentication.handlers.GoogleAuthProviderHandler.<init>(GoogleAuthProviderHandler.java:34)
        at dev.robingenz.capacitorjs.plugins.firebase.authentication.FirebaseAuthentication.initAuthProviderHandlers(FirebaseAuthentication.java:392)
        at dev.robingenz.capacitorjs.plugins.firebase.authentication.FirebaseAuthentication.<init>(FirebaseAuthentication.java:51)
        at dev.robingenz.capacitorjs.plugins.firebase.authentication.FirebaseAuthenticationPlugin.load(FirebaseAuthenticationPlugin.java:38)
        at com.getcapacitor.PluginHandle.load(PluginHandle.java:95)
        at com.getcapacitor.PluginHandle.<init>(PluginHandle.java:59)
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.registerPlugin(Bridge.java:509)
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.registerAllPlugins(Bridge.java:464)
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.<init>(Bridge.java:191)
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.<init>(Bridge.java:65)
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge$Builder.create(Bridge.java:1308)
        at com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity.load(BridgeActivity.java:72)
        at com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity.onStart(BridgeActivity.java:110)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1455)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3946)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2423)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8333)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1065)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~xzGX5coTs3h0rQrebH6mtw==/com.learn2earn.fcm-ayDF2ytKAEXW8dRbbk151A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~xzGX5coTs3h0rQrebH6mtw==/com.learn2earn.fcm-ayDF2ytKAEXW8dRbbk151A==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at dev.robingenz.capacitorjs.plugins.firebase.authentication.handlers.GoogleAuthProviderHandler.buildGoogleSignInClient(GoogleAuthProviderHandler.java:100) 
        at dev.robingenz.capacitorjs.plugins.firebase.authentication.handlers.GoogleAuthProviderHandler.buildGoogleSignInClient(GoogleAuthProviderHandler.java:78) 
        at dev.robingenz.capacitorjs.plugins.firebase.authentication.handlers.GoogleAuthProviderHandler.<init>(GoogleAuthProviderHandler.java:34) 
        at dev.robingenz.capacitorjs.plugins.firebase.authentication.FirebaseAuthentication.initAuthProviderHandlers(FirebaseAuthentication.java:392) 
        at dev.robingenz.capacitorjs.plugins.firebase.authentication.FirebaseAuthentication.<init>(FirebaseAuthentication.java:51) 
        at dev.robingenz.capacitorjs.plugins.firebase.authentication.FirebaseAuthenticationPlugin.load(FirebaseAuthenticationPlugin.java:38) 
        at com.getcapacitor.PluginHandle.load(PluginHandle.java:95) 
        at com.getcapacitor.PluginHandle.<init>(PluginHandle.java:59) 
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.registerPlugin(Bridge.java:509) 
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.registerAllPlugins(Bridge.java:464) 
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.<init>(Bridge.java:191) 
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.<init>(Bridge.java:65) 
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge$Builder.create(Bridge.java:1308) 
        at com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity.load(BridgeActivity.java:72) 
        at com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity.onStart(BridgeActivity.java:110) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1455) 
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8388) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3946) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2423) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8333) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1065) ```

Unable to debug this issue for a week. I tried to check if there is a conflict with any of the plugins that are being used. But was not able to figure it out. How do I fix this?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this plugin:

```
"@capacitor-firebase/authentication": "^0.3.1"
```

with the current version of it:

```
"@capacitor-firebase/authentication": "^0.5.0"
```

Also see this [issue comment](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase/issues/60#issuecomment-1087069893), which may or may not be still actual.

Comment: the main issue was that i haven't used this rgcfaIncludeGoogle = true

Comment: now i am getting this error          2022-07-07 12:16:50.882 7983-7983/com.learn2earn.fcm E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/vendor.js - Line 106530 - Msg: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: 10: 
    Error: 10: 
        at cap.fromNative (http://localhost/:414:32)
        at <anonymous>:1:18

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49450870/6731412 for `Error: 10`.