# Ionic 6 - Google Sign In React - "code":"10"

Tags: reactjs, oauth, ionic5, sign-in-with-google

I am using this plugin in my Ionic app (react) to use Sign In With Google Functionality.
https://github.com/CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth

D/Capacitor: Unable to find a Capacitor plugin to handle requestCode, trying Cordova plugins 147138663
D/Capacitor: Sending plugin error: {"save":false,"callbackId":"1887292","pluginId":"GoogleAuth","methodName":"signIn","success":false,"error":{"message":"Something went wrong","code":"10"}}

I am using this plugin in my Ionic app (react) to use Sign In With Google Functionality.
https://github.com/CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth

Followed this tutorial -
https://enappd.com/blog/google-login-in-ionic-react-capacitor-apps/122/

Created the following on google console -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3BNt.png)

I generated SHA1 using the following tool -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Cb8.png)

I still get a Code 10

D/Capacitor: Unable to find a Capacitor plugin to handle requestCode, trying Cordova plugins 147138663
D/Capacitor: Sending plugin error: {"save":false,"callbackId":"1887292","pluginId":"GoogleAuth","methodName":"signIn","success":false,"error":{"message":"Something went wrong","code":"10"}}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: MainActivity.java

package com.xyz.starter;
import com.codetrixstudio.capacitor.GoogleAuth.GoogleAuth;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        registerPlugin(GoogleAuth.class);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

Comment: Please check this link
`https://stackoverflow.com/a/49450870/10805479`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google SignIn API Exception 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450140/google-signin-api-exception-10)